# How do I save a tensorflow ML model without a session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

When I look this problem up I find solutions using a session variable. I am not using a session variable so these do not work. I have also tried `tf.keras.models.save_model` and `tf.keras.models.load_model` but when I run the load_model I get an error relating to not being able to access the file.

Is there a best solution for this?

My error:
`KeyError: 0`

My training code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)

tf.keras.models.save_model(model,"model.h5",overwrite=True,
  include_optimizer=True)
```

My testing code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np

model = load_model("model.h5")

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
for i in range(25):
  plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.imshow(x_test[i])
  plt.xlabel(np.argmax(model.predict(x_test)[i]))  

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message and the full code. I don't see you trying to save and reload the model.

Comment: It has been updated